# UI.Router confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

Look at the code snippet below. The console output is:

- In MainController

Questions:

1. Why don't I see "In Main Resolve" in console output?
2. Also, I have `<ui-view></ui-view>` in *index.html*. The partial *dashoard.html* gets loaded there. Why? I never said to go to that state.

   ```
   angular.module('main',['ui.router'])
       .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider) {
           $stateProvider
               .state('main', {
                       url: '/',
                       templateUrl: 'index.html',  
                       controller: 'MainController',
                       resolve: {
                           ResA:  function() {
                               console.log('In Main Resolve');
                           }
                       }
               })
               .state('dashboard', {
                       url:'/dashboard',
                       templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
                       controller: 'dashCtrl'
               });

       }])
       .controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope) {
           console.log('In MainController');
           $scope.A = "John";
           $scope.B = "Doe";

       }])
       .controller('dashCtrl',function($scope) {
           $scope.Name = "Hello World"
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what is not working for you - because I used your code **`1 : 1`** in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BQU5HX2yO5V9ugezSdG?p=preview) - and it is working as expected.

The only change is, that instead of *`index.html`*, I used **`tpl.html`** - because `index.html` is simply the Root - Single Page.

*And exactly that could be causing all the issues. Other words, index.html seem to be targeting the root...*

```
.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  //templateUrl: 'index.html',
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  controller: 'MainController',
  resolve: {
    ResA: function() {
      console.log('In Main Resolve');
    }
  }
})
```

Going to this state, console writes:

```
In Main Resolve
In MainController
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BQU5HX2yO5V9ugezSdG?p=preview)